# Visual Basic Console - Integer that would randomly generate every times its used

Tags: vb.net, random, console-application, basic

What i'm basicly looking to do here is create somewhat of a dice that would be rolled everytime I ask it to be used in an equation. For example if I create a d10 and use the following code:

```
Dim PlayerStr As Integer
PlayerStr = 2
Dim PlayerHit As Integer    
PlayerHit = d10 + PlayerStr
```

Is there are way for me to use the d10 again later in the code for example for something like this `Enemyhit = d10 + enemystr` and have the d10 be "rolled" both times? I've tried doing it this way

```
Module Module1

    Public RNG As New Random
    Public d10 As Integer
    d10 = RNG.next(1, 11)
Sub Main ()
...
End Sub

End Module
```

But as far as I understand this it would roll the d10 once the program starts and then use that value every time it would be told to use the d10 or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of re-using the Integer variable, re-use a function that returns a random Integer:

```
Private m_rng As New Random()

Private Function Roll()

    Dim d10 As Integer
    d10 = m_rng.next(1, 11)

    Return d10

End Function
```

Then use it like this:

```
PlayerHit = Roll() + PlayerStr
```

And:

```
Enemyhit = Roll() + enemystr
```

Comment: If the method is called several times in the same tick the "same" (equal) Random instance will be created which will gives the same value when calling Next. Consider using a single Random instance and calling next on it each time you need.

Comment: Note that you could also have used a [Static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx) variable (not to mistake with Shared). That way you can keep the random instance inside the method if you only need it there ; but that's more a "preference-based" thing.

Comment: Hey just wondering if I create another function in the same way can I use the m_rng.next or for say a d4 as well or should I make a new Random?

Comment: I think you can use the same random, just do Next(1, 5) instead of Next(1, 11).